# C# Cross-Project Assembly References - When to recompile

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say that I have two projects, PluginA and PluginB, which each build a DLL, PluginA.dll and PluginB.dll.

PluginA (v1.0) has a public string property:

```
namespace PluginA
{
  public static class Config
  {
    public static string SharedConfig { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This property is set by PluginB (also v1.0) when that assembly loads:

```
namespace PluginB
{
  public class Loader
  {
    public void Initialize()
    {
      PluginA.Config.SharedConfig = "xyz";
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I'm curious if I need to recompile PluginB after certain changes to PluginA. For example, let's say I update PluginA's version to v1.1 and I add some new, unrelated code. Does PluginB have to be recompiled, or will it continue to work as-is with the new version of PluginA?

If it needs to be recompiled, is it because of the version change, or because of the code change, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you are not referencing the PluginA using Specific Version and as long as the accessed from another assembly members are in the samel place it doesn't have to be recompiled. It would work.

Although if your PluginB is accessing constant members from your PluginA and let's say you changed the values of the constant members inside PluginA, PluginB doesn't have to be recompiled **but** it would use old values. So you'll have to manually recompile your PluginB as it copies the constant values into it's own manifest when it "sees" that it's a constant.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you sould add reference by Project to make sure that you always get the newest version.

Let's take a look [this](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-add-references-your-visual-studio-project.cfm) guideline.[image]